# How can I check whether a user is a member of a Telegram group?

Tags: java, scala, api, telegram

I'd like to use the Telegram API to confirm that a given user is a member of a named group. I can successfully authenticate as the user given their phone number and the code that they get sent, but beyond that I'm pretty lost. I thought I could start with `client.contactsSearch` with `@groupname`, but that returns me an empty vector.

I'm using the Kotlogram library from Scala, but it's just a thin wrapper around the MT protocol.

Comment: It can done by bot API, would you like to know that?

Comment: I posted my solution as an answer, but I'd be happy to see how it compares to another solution. The bot API is HTTP, isn't it? That might be preferable, because at least I can use that asynchronously.

Answer (score 5):

For Bot API, you can use [getChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember) method.

The result will contain `status` for [member](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?getChatMember-357d23e4), [left](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?getChatMember-755f1e78), etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with in the end. I don't know whether it's the optimal approach, though.

```scala
val PhoneNumber = "+1..."

val app = new TelegramApp(..., "...", "...", "0.0.1", "0.0.1", "en")

class ApiStorage extends TelegramApiStorage {
    ...
}

val client = Kotlogram.getDefaultClient(app, new ApiStorage)

val sentCode = client.authSendCode(false, PhoneNumber, true)
val code = scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
val authorization = client.authSignIn(PhoneNumber, sentCode.getPhoneCodeHash, code)

val self = authorization.getUser.getAsUser

val name = s"${self.getFirstName} ${self.getLastName}"

val userInput = new TLInputUser(self.getId, self.getAccessHash)

client.contactsSearch("@groupname", 100).getChats.toArray.map(_.asInstanceOf[TLChannel]).find(_.getUsername == "groupname") match {
    case Some(channel) =>
        val channelInput = new TLInputChannel(channel.getId, channel.getAccessHash)
        val isMember = Try { client.channelsGetParticipant(channelInput, userInput) } map { _ => true } getOrElse false
        if (isMember) {
            println("Is a member")
        } else {
            println("Is not a member")
        }

    case None =>
        println("Can't find channel @groupname")
}

client.close()
```